# Google map turns grey after loading correctly at first

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

On http://dev.coinjabber.com/site/evrnyc.com the google map with the element ID googgleMap loads the correct address at first, but then suddenly turns grey. Why is that?

Comment: why this element is not an iframe?

Comment: Google Maps Embed API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start

Comment: I went by this example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Comment: In JavaScript + HTML you can see, It will draw the map in `<div id="map-canvas"></div>` I can't find this element? Did you change the id to "googgleMap ". Why? What is the reason?

Comment: I guess I figured it out, I had to change the function load to:
<script>

$(window).bind("load", function() {
   codeAddress();
});
</script>

 instead of <script>
   codeAddress();
</script>

Answer (score 1):

guess I figured it out, I had to change the function load to: `<script> $(window).bind("load", function() { codeAddress(); }); </script>` instead of `<script> codeAddress(); </script>`